# Does GROUP BY in any way imply the records' order?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Consider the following code:

```
SELECT s, COUNT(*)
FROM p
GROUP BY s;
```

Should I expect the records to be sorted with respect to s? In my experience, in Access 2007, it seems to be the case that the command implies an order.

Answer (score 5):

You should never make that assumption when using SQL.  It is always best to add an explicit `ORDER BY`:

```
order by s
```

This is because SQL (the language) does not guarantee the ordering of result sets with no `ORDER BY`.

That said, MS Access is going to return the results in order, because I think it has only one algorithm for calculating `ORDER BY` -- sorting the list.

However, other algorithms are definitely out there.  SQL Server, for instance, has hash-based algorithms and parallel algorithms.

So, you might as well learn how to write correct queries.